# Определение значения для кнопки типа submit

Tags: php, html, post, input, button

Есть форма

```html
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Ваш возраст: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Как в php коде определить нажата ли кнопка `<input type="submit" />`?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['submit']));` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ответ неверный

Comment: Чтобы определить значение для инпута, его надо **задать**. Л - Логика. Причем задать как значение, так и имя.

Comment: как вариант - можно не вообще проверять значение инпута. зависит от задачи

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Ваш возраст: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <?php
 $error="Кнопка нажата!";
 echo '<p><input type="submit" onclick="cansel()" class="blue" value="Кнопка"></p>';
 echo "<script>function cansel(){var txt; var r=confirm('".$error."'); if(r == false){document.open('action.php'); }} </script>";
 ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Специально для вас повторю вопрос, "Как **в php коде** определить"

Comment: ну тогда так =) https://fooobar.com/questions/7826506/write-to-file-upon-button-press

Comment: Смешно. По этой ссыылке примерно в 50 раз больше кода чем нужно, но при этом он вообше не отвечает на заднный вопрос :)